# linux + print message on the screen after login to linux machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting, ksh, login-script

I have linux machine red-hat 5.1

I want to write ksh/bash script that perform the following

1. Each time that someone login to the linux machine

   then he will get the following message on the screen - after entering login/password

   ```
       PLEASE DONT DO anything on this Linux machine !!!!
   ```

Please advice how to do that ? And where to put the ksh/bash script ?

Comment: why I get -1 - what wrong on my Question -:( -:( -:(

Comment: Probably not professional enough question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/motd` file, no script needed.

Comment: If the users are connecting via SSH, we'll need to make sure `PrintMotd yes` is set in sshd_config yes?